# How to store integer value in arrays.xml file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

in arrays.xml i declared 1 array like this:

```
   <string-array name="music_code">
      <item>1</item>
      <item>2</item>
       <item>3</item>
       <item>4</item>
  </string-array>
```

and in other Activity extends from PreferenceActivity, i declared:

```
int value = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
          .getInt("music_code, 1);
```

But there is error when running. so why?
I also changed above xml code like this:

```
 <array name="music_code">
      <item>1</item>
      <item>2</item>
       <item>3</item>
       <item>4</item>
  </array>
```

help me please! thank

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the array before you can retrieve values from it. I have an example below, also maybe ContentValues would be more suitable for your needs?

```
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.music_code);
int value = Integer.parseInt(array[INDEX]);
```

You can also use ContentValues if you need to index values, or a database if you need more control over retrieving and saving them. ContentValues is as such:

```
int value = 5;
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("KEY", value);
int val = cv.get("KEY");
```